# React - `createPortal` with `document.body` causes click event to fire immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling, event-propagation, react-portal

My app has a button called `Open Modal`. When this button is clicked, a modal is appended to the `document.body` using `createPortal`. [**Link to demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-createportal-useeffect-5ynb6?file=/src/index.js:412-655)

Once the modal has been mounted (i.e. `isOpen === true`), I would like to print some text to the console each time the user clicks somewhere on the page.

To do this, I'm using a `useEffect` hook to bind a click event to the `document` object if `isOpen === true`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const eventHandler = () => console.log("You clicked me");

    if (isOpen) {
      document.addEventListener("click", eventHandler);
    }

  }, [isOpen]);
```

When the user clicks 'Open Modal' for the first time, `isOpen` changes from `false` to `true`, this causes the component to re-render. Once the re-render is complete, the click event in the above effect is registered.

**Problem**

Clicking 'Open Modal' for the first time causes the `document`'s click event to fire (you can see the event handler's output in the console). This doesn't make sense to me - **how is it possible for the click event on `document` to already be registered by the time the first 'Open Modal' click has propagated up to it?**

**Expected behaviour**

The first click on 'Open Modal' should only result in the `document`'s click event being registered, the event itself should not fire at this point.

If I omit `createPortal` (see line 38 of the demo), the app works as expected, i.e. the event is registered on the first click on 'Open Modal' and the event handler is called on all *subsequent* clicks on the page.

The app also works as expected if I mount the modal to a sibling of the app root instead of `document.body` (see line 39 of the demo). So the problem described above only occurs when `createPortal` is used with `document.body` as the container, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly, But I think, the problem occurring because of `Event Propagation`, By the time propagation completes, document `click` event is been registered, that might be reason it's calling the `eventHandler`. Correct me if am I'm wrong.

If you stop the event propagation, it's working fine.

```
const openModal = useCallback(
    function (e) {
      if (!isOpen) { // stopping the propagation
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      setOpen(true);
    },
    [setOpen, isOpen]
  );
```

Demo link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-createportal-useeffect-forked-z16yp?file=/src/index.js:313-475)

Comment: Thank you @Naren. This could very well be the reason, although I can't wrap my head around what's going on exactly, hopefully someone could shed some more light on that. Why does using `createPortal` seem to "slow" propagation? Especially if the event is being registered after rendering is complete? The app works as expected without `createPortal`.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504546/is-it-safe-to-use-reactdom-createportal-with-document-body) provides some insight as to why it's a bad idea to use `createPortal` with `document.body`. I don't know enough about native vs synthetic events to explain the behaviour in my post though.

Comment: Appending the modal to a sibling of the app root instead of `document.body` works - [see line 39](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-createportal-useeffect-5ynb6?file=/src/index.js:855-939).

Comment: Did you check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals)

Comment: Yes, I had read that before attempting to use `createPortal`. If you check out the demo in my last comment, you'll see I'm using their idea of appending the modal to a sibling div of the app root instead of the `document.body` itself (line 39) - this makes everything work as expected. But I'm still not sure why using `createPortal` *with* `document.body` messes up propagation.

Comment: yeah, Adding to child is working fine but not sure what’s wrong with the document.body